# I think my rails gem is broken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

So I'm working on one computer with some ruby/rails code and its working fine.

On another computer however I'm having a problem when trying to create a model or run the server and it looks like the same problem. look at this output:

```
$>script/generate 
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:271:in `require_frameworks': no such file to load -- net/https (RuntimeError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:134:in `process'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
    from /home/aaron/NetBeansProjects/online-scheduler/config/environment.rb:9
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/commands/generate.rb:1
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from script/generate:3
$>script/server
=> Booting Mongrel
=> Rails 2.3.5 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:271:in `require_frameworks': no such file to load -- net/https (RuntimeError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:134:in `process'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
    from /home/aaron/NetBeansProjects/online-scheduler/config/environment.rb:9
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/commands/server.rb:84
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from script/server:3
$>
```

Now on the other computer the script/generate should be showing me a list of generate commands that I can use... so whats the deal?

Comment: Well, if you think that just the gem is broken, then try "sudo gem uninstall rails && sudo gem install rails" to reinstall it...

Comment: @Sam Ubuntu 9.10.
@severin: It's not always that simple. The problem WAS fixed when I installed libopenssl-ruby1.8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this article that says to install libopenssl-ruby1.8- 
http://rails.anyware-technologies.com.br/2009/04/09/rails-23-on-debian/